# My body leaves; my core can stay

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

My body leaves; my core can stay,
Where I shall breathe another way.
The route of south I always linger.
My arms have arms; my ring no finger.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you a:

> tree?

My body leaves; my core can stay,

> A double meaning: The body is leafs/leaves, and when they go away for the winter, the trunk/core remains

Where I shall breathe another way.

> With no leaves, a tree can still exchange oxygen and CO2, just in a more dormant state

The route of south I always linger.

> Route/root is another double meaning. [Via OP: roots stretch downward, and are harder to move the deeper they go]

My arms have arms; my ring no finger.

> The arms are branches, which can have more branches stemming from them.  Tree trunks can have rings, but do not have fingers.

Comment: Ah: (rot13) *Gur shegure fbhgu, gur yngre yrnirf yrnir*?

Comment: Spoiler for line 3 since you're on the right lines: (rot13) Ebbgf tb qbjajneq jurer gur gerr erfvqrf

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

Are you:

> A planet or galaxy?

My rough thinking:

> When a big planet explodes, it leaves its core behind. Also, planets have rings...
>  A galaxy have arms :) I have no idea how the other hints apply to this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Black hole ?

Because :

> A black hole is the core of a former star, whose most of its matter was expulsed through space via a supernova.
> Black holes are often surrounded by rings of hot gas. No idea for the arms or the south hints though.

Comment: The arms might be rot13([dhnfnef](http://www.seasky.org/celestial-objects/quasars.html)) but it seems like a bit of a stretch, I suppose.